# unity xcode an error occurred during export codesign failed

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, code-signing

My unity game runs on the iphone when deploying directly.

But when I archive & export to upload for the appstore, I keep getting:

> an error occurred during export codesign failed

Notes:

I tried navigating to: https://:Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourprojectname/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos

But it was empty ( so removing yourApp.app won't fix the issue )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1- when selecting export i was getting a screen with the app name & another bundle name

2- the bundle states 0 entitlements & it has no provisioning profile next to it

3- find the bundle in xcode build phases -> copy bundle resources

4- the bundle path should lead you to the unity asset causing the issue

5- the problem was solved for me after deleting the asset the was causing the issue ( luckily it was an editor helper asset & can be deleted )

Hope this helps.